# Achievements tab isn't working in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, top-bar, achievements-dialog

When I try to bring down the Achievements tab in Area 51, it's showing an error dialogue.

Strangely enough, the global inbox dropdown works just fine.

Could be connected to [this issue](/q/291459).

Screenshot:
[image: An error occurred while loading - please try again.]

Comment: Does the achievements dropdown work here on Meta for you?

Comment: Is the Linked section is not working? since there is  MSE question is linked, the Linked section is not displaying.

Comment: @AdamLear Yes, I checked just now,

Comment: @Adam and it's still not working, almost a month later. (my guess is SSL broke it)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You think every bug is due to SSL... ;)

Comment: @Adam well, SSL is the new caching, isn't it? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Area 51 fetches all topbar dialogs from Q&A sites through a private API. Some refactoring was done in A51 code recently that replaced old-school `string.Format` calls to construct the API URL with interpolated strings... a stray closing parenthesis snuck into the URL at that point, so naturally nothing worked.

The commit message said "HTTPS and area51.meta.stackexchange.com move", so I have to give this one to Shadow Wizard and [blame SSL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294909/achievements-tab-isnt-working-in-area-51?noredirect=1#comment959989_294909) on the purest of technicalities. ;)